# How can I order an IQueryable based on a field that is in another table?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am a newbie to `LINQ` and `c#` and I have two tables :

**Products**

**ProductStoreds**

`ProductStore` has a foreignKey to `Products` with a field named `ProductId`(same for both tables).
I have an IQueryable named `result` from `Products` table. how can I sort it based on a field named `status` in `ProductStore` Table.
this is what I have tried and I have not been successful:

```
result = result.Where(p =>
                p.ProductId == DbContext.ProductStores.Select(m => m.Product)
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.Status).ToInt());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join and order by Product like this

```
var stores = DbContext.ProductStores;
result = from store in stores
        join product in result on product.ProductId equals store.ProductId
        orderby store.Status
        select product;
```